# Pass file name as a string through command line into Maple

Tags: command-line, command-line-arguments, filenames, maple

I'm trying to use Maple function in external program using command-line interface. Data for function is to be passed through file. For demonstration of the problem I created two files: /home/user_name/test.mpl and /home/user_name/test_data.txt.

test.mpl ("cat" demonstrates use of Maple function):

```
#filename := "/home/user_name/test_data.txt":
print(filename):

i := parse(readline(filename)):
poly := parse(readline(filename)):
s := parse(readline(filename)):

print(cat(convert(poly+i,string), " ", s)):
```

test_data.txt :

```
1
x^2 * y + 1
"A string."
```

According to the [manual](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=ProgrammingGuide/Chapter14), I can use something like this (but this example doesn't cover usage of two files, one as a code and another as an argument):

```
/usr/local/maple/bin/maple -c 'datafile:="/tmp/12345.data";' -c N:=1;
```

When I try

```
/path/to/maple -c 'filename:="/home/user_name/test_data.txt":' -q /home/user_name/test.mpl
```

I get the following error:

```
Error, incorrect syntax in parse: `/` unexpected (near 11th character of parsed string)
```

If I delete first `/` in filename string, I get the following output (before the errors related to `readline`):

```
/        home       \
|-------------------| . txt
\user_name test_data/
```

It clearly demonstrates that file path is not parsed as a string (but probably as some kind of expression). Probably I should use some escape sequences, for Maple or for shell, but none of my attempts worked.

If I get file name inside test.mpl (uncommenting first line there and removing `-c` parameter), it works though, but that's not what I need.

How to pass file name as a string through command line (probably not with using `-c`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me using commandline Maple on Linux, as say,

```
/path/to/maple -c 'filename:=\"/home/user_name/test_data.txt\":' -q /home/user_name/test.mpl
```